# .Create is missing - deployment to WildFly server

Tags: hibernate, jboss, wildfly

I get the following output, when i try to deploy my web-application Testmodule to the Wildfly server. I was trying to configure a security module, i.e. a user authentication before getting to the application.

Usages:
Hibernate 2.1
Wildfly Server 8.2

Console output:

```
13:11:22,311 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Testmodule.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Testmodule.UndertowDeploymentInfoService is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.secureDomain]",
"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Testmodule.war\".component.DatenManager.CREATE is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.secureDomain]"]}
```

jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>secureDomain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>HtmlAuth</web-resource-name>
            <description>application security constraints</description>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Sample Realm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

standalone.xml:

```
...
<security-domain name="secureDomain" cache-type="default">
   <authentication>
      <login-module flag="required" code="Database">
         <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/dbexample"/>
         <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select passwd from    wildfly_users where username=?"/>
         <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role, 'Roles' from wildfly_userroles where username=?"/>
      </login-module>
   </authentication>
</security-domain>
...
```

I tried to replicate the example in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783286237) book, but it fails with the above error. I am a total greenhorn with Wildfly and its configuration, would be helpful if someone could tell me what the error means, why it occurs and how to fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

Make sure security is loaded in your standalone.xml:

```
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
```

Make sure that your security domain is loading properly, check the logs thoroughly for errors related to that not loading. Most likely cause would be that the jndi datasource lookup is failing.

Try changing the lookup in jboss-web.xml to the full jndi name:

```
<security-domain>java:/jaas/secureDomain</security-domain>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I have gone through them. The security module is being loaded correctly and the datasource connection is working just fine. The application behind the authentication uses this db-connection to extract and merge data. Using the full jndi name didn't change anything, the error remains. What i did find out though is, that if I remove the jboss-web.xml I get an authentication, but when i try to login with the merged data from the database, it fails to authenticate. In this case I think he doesn't know what credentials to use because of the missing info about the database.